# Async vs synchronous XMLHttpRequest on window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a XMLHttpRequest POST which occurs when the user tries to leave the page or close the browser tab. It basically sends some timing data back to an API.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {     
    xmlhttp.open("POST", 'http://somewebste.com/api', false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(some_data);
}
```

I'm wondering if the open function should be sync or async? (set as "false" or "true" in the xmlhttp.open line).

Maybe it doesn't matter? But I've read some conflicting opinions online. I'm not sure which one is best and why.

Thank you.

Comment: suggest [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) where it's supported, otherwise it'd have to be synchronous, but I read the IE10/11 actually do not support synchronous xmlhttprequest at all

Comment: Can I ask why it would need to be synchronous?

Comment: I guess if you don't care about  a response, synch would do